# How to display javascript results on the same page

Tags: javascript

I was wondering instead of using the alert function to show the function result if there was a way to print it in a text field on the same page underneath the Calculate Button. Here is what I have so far:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/formula_styles.css">

 <script type="text/javascript">

  var a,b,c;
  function setValues1()
  {
   a = Number(document.getElementById("a").value);
   b = Number(document.getElementById("b").value);
   c = Number(document.getElementById("c").value);
  }

  function and()
  {
   setValues1();
   result1 = (-b + Math.sqrt(b*b -4*a*c))/(2*a);
   result2 = (-b - Math.sqrt(b*b -4*a*c))/(2*a);
   alert("The volume of this cube is " +result1 + " and " +result2);
  }

 </script>

</head>
<body>

<nav>
 <a href="index.html">Home</a> // <a href="levels.html">Grade Levels</a>
</nav>

<div id="container">
 <div id="formula"> 
  <input type="text" id="a" placeholder="'A' Variable"/><br>
  <input type="text" id="b" placeholder="'B' Variable"/><br>
  <input type="text" id="c" placeholder="'C' Variable"/><br>
  <input type="button" onclick="and()" value="Calculate!"/>
 </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You may need to state what the problem you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add an element to your html, something like this:

```
<div id="results"></div>
```

Then instead of using an alert, you can do something along the lines of this:

```
document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "The volume of this cube is " +result1 + " and " +result2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a `div` under the button and populate the `innerHTML` of the `div`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/formula_styles.css">

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var a, b, c;

    function setValues1() {
      a = Number(document.getElementById("a").value);
      b = Number(document.getElementById("b").value);
      c = Number(document.getElementById("c").value);
    }

    function and() {
      setValues1();
      result1 = (-b + Math.sqrt(b * b - 4 * a * c)) / (2 * a);
      result2 = (-b - Math.sqrt(b * b - 4 * a * c)) / (2 * a);
      document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = "The volume of this cube is " + result1 + " and " + result2;
    }
  </script>

</head>

<body>

  <nav>
    <a href="index.html">Home</a> // <a href="levels.html">Grade Levels</a>
  </nav>

  <div id="container">
    <div id="formula">
      <input type="text" id="a" placeholder="'A' Variable" />
      <br>
      <input type="text" id="b" placeholder="'B' Variable" />
      <br>
      <input type="text" id="c" placeholder="'C' Variable" />
      <br>
      <input type="button" onclick="and()" value="Calculate!" />
      <div id="result">

      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by setting up an element you wish to contain the text.

```
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "The volume of this cube is " +result1 + " and " + result2;
```

To do this you need set the element up with an ID of result.

This line of code is calling the function `getElementByID` to get the element, which then lets you change its `innerHTML` property.

The element you assign to this can be whatever you want it to be.