# Changing the method that results are displayed in a quiz

Tags: javascript

I have a quiz that takes the scores the responses against categories and displays the results in a new page. It works but I want to make two adjustments:

1. I want to change the link on page one to generate the results to a button.
2. I want the results to display beneath the button instead of a new page.
   [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30495561/how-to-display-javascript-results-on-the-same-page) is what I'm trying to accomplish, but I can't figure out how to apply it to my code.

```html
<!doctype html>

<head>

  <script>
    // Function to create arrays
    function makeArray(len) {
      for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) this[i] = null;
      this.length = len
    }

    // Create array to hold gifts
    gifts = new makeArray(7);
    gifts[0] = '<a href="https://visitacf.com/spiritual-gift-definitions/#exhorter" style="padding-left:10px;" target="new">Define<\/a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>Exhorter/Encourager<\/b>',
      gifts[1] = '<a href="https://visitacf.com/spiritual-gift-definitions/#giver" style="padding-left:10px;" target="new">Define<\/a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>Giver<\/b>',
      gifts[2] = '<a href="https://visitacf.com/spiritual-gift-definitions/#leader" style="padding-left:10px;" target="new">Define<\/a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>Leader/Administrator<\/b>',
      gifts[3] = '<a href="https://visitacf.com/spiritual-gift-definitions/#mercy" style="padding-left:10px;" target="new">Define<\/a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>Mercy/Compassion<\/b>',
      gifts[4] = '<a href="https://visitacf.com/spiritual-gift-definitions/#prophet" style="padding-left:10px;" target="new">Define<\/a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>Prophet/Perceiver<\/b>',
      gifts[5] = '<a href="https://visitacf.com/spiritual-gift-definitions/#server" style="padding-left:10px;" target="new">Define<\/a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>Server<\/b>',
      gifts[6] = '<a href="https://visitacf.com/spiritual-gift-definitions/#teacher" style="padding-left:10px;" target="new">Define<\/a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>Teacher<\/b>';

    // The question object constructor function
    function makeQuestion(question, giftno) {
      this.question = question;
      this.giftno = giftno;
      this.useranswer = null;
      this.showForm = showForm;
      this.userChoices = new makeArray(5);
      this.userChoices[0] = " Never",
        this.userChoices[1] = " Rarely",
        this.userChoices[2] = " Sometimes",
        this.userChoices[3] = " Often";
      this.userChoices[4] = " Always";
    }

    // The evaluation object constructor function
    function makeEvaluation(giftno) {
      this.giftno = giftno;
      this.gift = null;
      this.giftsum = null;
    }

    // Function to evaluate the quiz
    function evaluate() {
      for (var i = 0; i < grade.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < quiz.length; j++) {
          if (grade[i].giftno == quiz[j].giftno) {
            grade[i].giftsum += quiz[j].useranswer;
          }
        }
      }
    }

    // Method to display contents of question object.
    function showForm(n) {
      document.write((n + 1) + '. ' + this.question + '<blockquote><form>');
      for (var i = 0; i < this.userChoices.length; i++) {
        document.write('<input type = "radio" name = "q' + n +
          '" onClick = "quiz[' + n + '].useranswer = ' + i + '">');
        document.write(this.userChoices[i] + '<br />');
      }
      document.write('<\/form><\/blockquote>');
    }

    // Function to display the assessment
    function assesQuiz() {
      evaluate();
      var evalPage = '<html lang="en">';
      evalPage += '<head>';
      evalPage += '<title>Spiritual Gifts Test Results<\/title>';
      evalPage += '<\/head>';
      evalPage += '<body>';

      evalPage += '<div id="content-test">';
      evalPage += '<center><br/>';
      evalPage += '<\/center>';

      evalPage += '<blockquote>The Spiritual Gifts Test you just took assesses which of the seven gifts listed in Romans 12:6-8 you may have.<\/blockquote>';
      evalPage += '<blockquote>You can learn more about your gift by clicking on the word "define." <\/blockquote>';
      evalPage += '<p>'
      evalPage += '<br />'

      for (var i = 0; i < grade.length; i++) {
        evalPage += grade[i].gift + ' - ' + grade[i].giftsum + '<br />&nbsp;<br />';
      }
      evalPage += '<\/p>'
      evalPage += '<br/>';
      evalPage += '<a href="https://visitacf.churchcenter.com/people/forms/100259" target="_blank">Submit your results<\/a>';
      evalPage += '<\/div>';
      evalPage += '<\/div>';
      evalPage += '<\/body><\/html>';
      document.write(evalPage);
      document.close();
    }

    // Create evaluation array (grade)
    grade = new makeArray(7);
    for (var i = 0; i < grade.length; i++) {
      grade[i] = new makeEvaluation(i);
      grade[i].giftno = i;
      grade[i].giftsum = 0;
      grade[i].gift = gifts[i];
    }

    // Create question objects...
    quiz = new makeArray(42);
    quiz[0] = new makeQuestion("I relate & measure everything I experience accordingly to God’s Word.", 4),
      quiz[1] = new makeQuestion("Others seem to look to me for advice and help.", 0);
    quiz[2] = new makeQuestion("I’m easily bothered by others’ lack of compassion.", 3);
    quiz[3] = new makeQuestion("I don’t take anything at face value.", 6);
    quiz[4] = new makeQuestion("I can visualize the “big picture” of a major project.", 2);
    quiz[5] = new makeQuestion("When others are in my home I like to wait on them “hand and foot”.", 5);
    quiz[6] = new makeQuestion("I feel compelled to give financially to others.", 1);
    quiz[7] = new makeQuestion("I will speak the truth whether or not it causes hurt feelings.", 4);
    quiz[8] = new makeQuestion("I can organize and delegate people and resources easily.", 2);
    quiz[9] = new makeQuestion("I feel compelled to share knowledge.", 6);
    quiz[10] = new makeQuestion("Discouraged people are often encouraged by my words.", 0);
    quiz[11] = new makeQuestion("I neglect my own work in order to help others.", 5);
    quiz[12] = new makeQuestion("I easily identify tasks that need to get done and do them myself.", 5);
    quiz[13] = new makeQuestion("I enjoy doing little things to help people.", 5);
    quiz[14] = new makeQuestion("My natural tendency is to step up and take control.", 2);
    quiz[15] = new makeQuestion("I cheerfully give time or money, regardless of how much I have to give.", 1);
    quiz[16] = new makeQuestion("I have compassion for all living creatures.", 3);
    quiz[17] = new makeQuestion("I don’t hesitate to give constructive criticism.", 0);
    quiz[18] = new makeQuestion("People see me as a frank and outspoken person.", 4);
    quiz[19] = new makeQuestion("People seem to learn easily from me.", 6);
    quiz[20] = new makeQuestion("I can be described as responsible, charitable, and disciplined.", 1);
    quiz[21] = new makeQuestion("I don’t expect repayment for favors I do for others.", 1);
    quiz[22] = new makeQuestion("Others tell me I’m a good listener", 0);
    quiz[23] = new makeQuestion("Communicating the facts in a situation is something I do well.", 6);
    quiz[24] = new makeQuestion("I am a task oriented person.", 5);
    quiz[25] = new makeQuestion("I find it easy to maintain an optimistic outlook.", 0);
    quiz[26] = new makeQuestion("I will stand alone on something I believe in strongly.", 4);
    quiz[27] = new makeQuestion("I will not confront others if I feel it may hurt them.", 3);
    quiz[28] = new makeQuestion("I give well above my tithe to the Body of Christ.", 1);
    quiz[29] = new makeQuestion("While I’m frugal in personal spending, I’m often led to give to others.", 1);
    quiz[30] = new makeQuestion("I enjoy research as well as sharing what I find.", 6);
    quiz[31] = new makeQuestion("I am compelled to comfort people who are hurting or suffering.", 3);
    quiz[32] = new makeQuestion("Deadlines challenge me & usually meet them on time.", 2);
    quiz[33] = new makeQuestion("I can discern the motives of others fairly easily.", 4);
    quiz[34] = new makeQuestion("I find strength from bearing other’s burdens.", 3);
    quiz[35] = new makeQuestion("My use of knowledge may appear prideful.", 6);
    quiz[36] = new makeQuestion("I can create order out of organizational chaos.", 2);
    quiz[37] = new makeQuestion("I volunteer my time and talents to worthwhile causes.", 5);
    quiz[38] = new makeQuestion("I’m moved with compassion to cry with others.", 3);
    quiz[39] = new makeQuestion("I can select the best person for particular tasks.", 2);
    quiz[40] = new makeQuestion("My focus on right and wrong may be read as being judgmental.", 4);
    quiz[41] = new makeQuestion("I enjoy helping others develop a plan to deal with their concerns.", 0);
  </script>
</head>

<script>
  <!--
  // loop to display quiz
  for (var i = 0; i < quiz.length; i++) {
    quiz[i].showForm(i);
  }

  // reload bug fix
  if (navigator.appName == "Netscape" &&
    parseInt(navigator.appVersion) >= 3) {
    for (var i = 0; i < document.forms.length; i++) {
      document.forms[i].reset();
    }
  }

  //-->
</script>
<h4><a href="javascript:assesQuiz()">Click Here to Discover the Results of this Spiritual Gifts Inventory</a></h4><br/>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go

```html
<!doctype html>

<head>

  <script>
    // Function to create arrays
    function makeArray(len) {
      for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) this[i] = null;
      this.length = len
    }

    // Create array to hold gifts
    gifts = new makeArray(7);
    gifts[0] = '<a href="https://visitacf.com/spiritual-gift-definitions/#exhorter" style="padding-left:10px;" target="new">Define<\/a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>Exhorter/Encourager<\/b>',
      gifts[1] = '<a href="https://visitacf.com/spiritual-gift-definitions/#giver" style="padding-left:10px;" target="new">Define<\/a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>Giver<\/b>',
      gifts[2] = '<a href="https://visitacf.com/spiritual-gift-definitions/#leader" style="padding-left:10px;" target="new">Define<\/a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>Leader/Administrator<\/b>',
      gifts[3] = '<a href="https://visitacf.com/spiritual-gift-definitions/#mercy" style="padding-left:10px;" target="new">Define<\/a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>Mercy/Compassion<\/b>',
      gifts[4] = '<a href="https://visitacf.com/spiritual-gift-definitions/#prophet" style="padding-left:10px;" target="new">Define<\/a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>Prophet/Perceiver<\/b>',
      gifts[5] = '<a href="https://visitacf.com/spiritual-gift-definitions/#server" style="padding-left:10px;" target="new">Define<\/a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>Server<\/b>',
      gifts[6] = '<a href="https://visitacf.com/spiritual-gift-definitions/#teacher" style="padding-left:10px;" target="new">Define<\/a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>Teacher<\/b>';

    // The question object constructor function
    function makeQuestion(question, giftno) {
      this.question = question;
      this.giftno = giftno;
      this.useranswer = null;
      this.showForm = showForm;
      this.userChoices = new makeArray(5);
      this.userChoices[0] = " Never",
        this.userChoices[1] = " Rarely",
        this.userChoices[2] = " Sometimes",
        this.userChoices[3] = " Often";
      this.userChoices[4] = " Always";
    }

    // The evaluation object constructor function
    function makeEvaluation(giftno) {
      this.giftno = giftno;
      this.gift = null;
      this.giftsum = null;
    }

    // Function to evaluate the quiz
    function evaluate() {
      for (var i = 0; i < grade.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < quiz.length; j++) {
          if (grade[i].giftno == quiz[j].giftno) {
            grade[i].giftsum += quiz[j].useranswer;
          }
        }
      }
    }

    // Method to display contents of question object.
    function showForm(n) {
      document.write((n + 1) + '. ' + this.question + '<blockquote><form>');
      for (var i = 0; i < this.userChoices.length; i++) {
        document.write('<input type = "radio" name = "q' + n +
          '" onClick = "quiz[' + n + '].useranswer = ' + i + '">');
        document.write(this.userChoices[i] + '<br />');
      }
      document.write('<\/form><\/blockquote>');
    }

    // Function to display the assessment
    function assesQuiz() {
      evaluate();

      var evalPage = '<div id="content-test">';
      evalPage += '<center><br/>';
      evalPage += '<\/center>';

      evalPage += '<blockquote>The Spiritual Gifts Test you just took assesses which of the seven gifts listed in Romans 12:6-8 you may have.<\/blockquote>';
      evalPage += '<blockquote>You can learn more about your gift by clicking on the word "define." <\/blockquote>';
      evalPage += '<p>'
      evalPage += '<br />'

      for (var i = 0; i < grade.length; i++) {
        evalPage += grade[i].gift + ' - ' + grade[i].giftsum + '<br />&nbsp;<br />';
      }
      evalPage += '<\/p>'
      evalPage += '<br/>';
      evalPage += '<a href="https://visitacf.churchcenter.com/people/forms/100259" target="_blank">Submit your results<\/a>';
      evalPage += '<\/div>';
      evalPage += '<\/div>';
      document.querySelector('#results').innerHTML = evalPage;
    }

    // Create evaluation array (grade)
    grade = new makeArray(7);
    for (var i = 0; i < grade.length; i++) {
      grade[i] = new makeEvaluation(i);
      grade[i].giftno = i;
      grade[i].giftsum = 0;
      grade[i].gift = gifts[i];
    }

    // Create question objects...
    quiz = new makeArray(42);
    quiz[0] = new makeQuestion("I relate & measure everything I experience accordingly to God’s Word.", 4),
      quiz[1] = new makeQuestion("Others seem to look to me for advice and help.", 0);
    quiz[2] = new makeQuestion("I’m easily bothered by others’ lack of compassion.", 3);
    quiz[3] = new makeQuestion("I don’t take anything at face value.", 6);
    quiz[4] = new makeQuestion("I can visualize the “big picture” of a major project.", 2);
    quiz[5] = new makeQuestion("When others are in my home I like to wait on them “hand and foot”.", 5);
    quiz[6] = new makeQuestion("I feel compelled to give financially to others.", 1);
    quiz[7] = new makeQuestion("I will speak the truth whether or not it causes hurt feelings.", 4);
    quiz[8] = new makeQuestion("I can organize and delegate people and resources easily.", 2);
    quiz[9] = new makeQuestion("I feel compelled to share knowledge.", 6);
    quiz[10] = new makeQuestion("Discouraged people are often encouraged by my words.", 0);
    quiz[11] = new makeQuestion("I neglect my own work in order to help others.", 5);
    quiz[12] = new makeQuestion("I easily identify tasks that need to get done and do them myself.", 5);
    quiz[13] = new makeQuestion("I enjoy doing little things to help people.", 5);
    quiz[14] = new makeQuestion("My natural tendency is to step up and take control.", 2);
    quiz[15] = new makeQuestion("I cheerfully give time or money, regardless of how much I have to give.", 1);
    quiz[16] = new makeQuestion("I have compassion for all living creatures.", 3);
    quiz[17] = new makeQuestion("I don’t hesitate to give constructive criticism.", 0);
    quiz[18] = new makeQuestion("People see me as a frank and outspoken person.", 4);
    quiz[19] = new makeQuestion("People seem to learn easily from me.", 6);
    quiz[20] = new makeQuestion("I can be described as responsible, charitable, and disciplined.", 1);
    quiz[21] = new makeQuestion("I don’t expect repayment for favors I do for others.", 1);
    quiz[22] = new makeQuestion("Others tell me I’m a good listener", 0);
    quiz[23] = new makeQuestion("Communicating the facts in a situation is something I do well.", 6);
    quiz[24] = new makeQuestion("I am a task oriented person.", 5);
    quiz[25] = new makeQuestion("I find it easy to maintain an optimistic outlook.", 0);
    quiz[26] = new makeQuestion("I will stand alone on something I believe in strongly.", 4);
    quiz[27] = new makeQuestion("I will not confront others if I feel it may hurt them.", 3);
    quiz[28] = new makeQuestion("I give well above my tithe to the Body of Christ.", 1);
    quiz[29] = new makeQuestion("While I’m frugal in personal spending, I’m often led to give to others.", 1);
    quiz[30] = new makeQuestion("I enjoy research as well as sharing what I find.", 6);
    quiz[31] = new makeQuestion("I am compelled to comfort people who are hurting or suffering.", 3);
    quiz[32] = new makeQuestion("Deadlines challenge me & usually meet them on time.", 2);
    quiz[33] = new makeQuestion("I can discern the motives of others fairly easily.", 4);
    quiz[34] = new makeQuestion("I find strength from bearing other’s burdens.", 3);
    quiz[35] = new makeQuestion("My use of knowledge may appear prideful.", 6);
    quiz[36] = new makeQuestion("I can create order out of organizational chaos.", 2);
    quiz[37] = new makeQuestion("I volunteer my time and talents to worthwhile causes.", 5);
    quiz[38] = new makeQuestion("I’m moved with compassion to cry with others.", 3);
    quiz[39] = new makeQuestion("I can select the best person for particular tasks.", 2);
    quiz[40] = new makeQuestion("My focus on right and wrong may be read as being judgmental.", 4);
    quiz[41] = new makeQuestion("I enjoy helping others develop a plan to deal with their concerns.", 0);
  </script>
</head>

<script>
  <!--
  // loop to display quiz
  for (var i = 0; i < quiz.length; i++) {
    quiz[i].showForm(i);
  }

  // reload bug fix
  if (navigator.appName == "Netscape" &&
    parseInt(navigator.appVersion) >= 3) {
    for (var i = 0; i < document.forms.length; i++) {
      document.forms[i].reset();
    }
  }

  //-->
</script>
<a href="javascript:assesQuiz()"><button style="cursor:pointer">Click Here to Discover the Results of this Spiritual Gifts Inventory</button></a>
<br/>
<div id="results"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to do. Thank you!!